# Конкатенация видео разных размеров в ffmpeg

Tags: ffmpeg

Задача: есть множество файлов в mp4 разных размеров с разных камер. Нужно получить одно видео в mp4 с черным рамками, если не хватает по размеру. Главное чтобы было без искажений скейлинга. Итоговые пропорции должны быть 16:9.

пробовал следующее

> ffmpeg -f concat -i files.txt -aspect 16:9 -c:v mpeg4 output.mp4

Явно сделал что-то не так. Буду признателен за помощь.

Comment: что-то мне подсказывает что нужно использовать filter_complex

Answer (score 0):

На самом деле тут все было просто. Привел к общему разрешению все видео. Потом командой

> ffmpeg -f concat -i files.txt -c copy output.mp4

все успешно склеилось. Может пригодится кому